# Neo4j 2.0 cypher enforce unique username (create unique node or fail)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What is the best way to attempt to create a user but fail with appropriate feedback if the username is already taken?

Comment: It would seem the [MERGE](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M03/query-merge.html) command might be the solution, but I can't  figure a way to write a return that will let me know that nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not thread safe yet, but `MERGE` is the proper way to do this. You could do something like this, that sort of checks for a property matching something before returning. This kind of depends on the fact that timestamp() returns the same value for an entire query, which is documented: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-timestamp.

```
MERGE (u:User { username:"test" }) 
ON CREATE u 
SET u.created = timestamp() 
WITH u 
WHERE u.created = timestamp() 
RETURN u
```

The second time you run this, you don't get any results.

Comment: I have a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729347/merge-query-set-map-and-created-property-upon-creation

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to Wes' answer above, if you pass your own timestamp to the merge, you can avoid the `WITH` part of the Cypher.

```
MERGE (u:User { username:"test" })
ON CREATE u
SET u.created={myTimestamp}
RETURN u
```

Then simply check if the timestamp you supplied matches the one that was returned (ie. `u.created`). I needed a cypher like this, as it always returns the user object.

Comment: Is there any performance gain from this, or is it purely for readability?

Comment: As far I know adding `WITH` is like chaining multiple cyphers, but I doubt in this case there is any real performance difference. The primary reason I like this method is because I needed to return the user, regardless of whether or not it was created.