# Merge query: set map and 'created' property upon creation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a user if it doesn't already exist, then know whether creation occurred or not.

This syntax always perform the second set:

```
MERGE (n:User {email: {email}})
ON CREATE n
  SET n = {user}
  SET n.created = timestamp()
WITH n WHERE n.created = timestamp()
RETURN n
```

I'm guessing the second set isn't actually part of the ON CREATE clause, like so:

```
MERGE (n:User {email: {email}})
ON CREATE n
  SET n = {user}
SET n.created = timestamp()
WITH n WHERE n.created = timestamp()
RETURN n
```

However, the alternate syntax of multiple sets results in "Error: expected valid query body":

```
MERGE (n:User {email: {email}})
ON CREATE n
  SET n = {user}, n.created = timestamp()
WITH n WHERE n.created = timestamp()
RETURN n
```

As a workaround I've decided to pass the created time-stamp in with the user map, but is there a way to accomplish this?  Is it working as intended or is there a bug here, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

That last one should work IMO--can you make a github issue? We'll see what the neo guys say, but I think it should be ok to have comma separated sets.

As an alternative, you can do multiple ON CREATEs:

```
MERGE (n:User {email: {email}})
ON CREATE n
  SET n = {user}
ON CREATE n
  SET n.created = timestamp()
WITH n WHERE n.created = timestamp()
RETURN n
```

Comment: It doesn't seem you can mix and match setting maps and properties even with non-merge queries either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686010/neo4j-cypher-setting-a-map-and-property-yields-expected-valid-query-body.  Should I still create an issue for this, you think?  Or is this expected?

Comment: If you don't I will. :)

Comment: Unfortunately your proposed workaround doesn't seem to work.  I get `The property 'created' does not exist on Node[23036]`.  It doesn't seem to set the created timestamp.

Comment: Doh. Did you do it in the same order? Maybe try switching it around? (the two on creates). I wasn't actually able to test it.

Comment: I'm guessing it processes the map param set after everything and wipes it out. That doesn't seem right to me, either, but maybe you're not supposed to have two on creates. :/

Comment: That the order is irrelevant is surprising to me.  Quite strange.  We'll see what comes of the bug report, I guess.